# Where to find Ashley Williams on the Normandy 2?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I asked Ashley Williams to join my crew on the Normandy and she is a selectable member for my squad.

The strange thing is I can't seem to find her on the Normandy spaceship. It does not really make sense.

Is there a glitch possibly? This is for the PC version on Origin.

Comment: If you open the map while on the Normandy, if she is on the ship her name will appear on one of the decks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She is lying down on the floor on the left hand side of starboard observation deck, it took me ages to find her because you can't see her when you enter because she is behind the couch.

Answer (score 11):

She should be on the Crew Deck in the Starboard Observation deck - [source](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Normandy_SR-2#Deck_3:_Crew_Deck)

> Depending on where you are in the game she might be [having a bad hangover](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_xIPrbXxYA) on the floor

Comment: I'm disappointed Kaiden doesn't have the same scene.